# Plotting Bacteria according to Food Groups & Abundance in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that includes four bacteria types: R, B, P, Bi - this is in variable.x

value.y is their abundance and variable.y is various groups they are in.

I would like to plot them according to their food categories: "FiberCategory", "FruitCategory", "VegetablesCategory" & "WholegrainCategory." I have made 4 separate files that have the as such:

```
Sample   Bacteria   Abundance   Category Level
30841102    R       0.005293192 1        Low
30841102    P       0.000002570 1        Low
30841102    B       0.005813275 1        Low
30841102    Bi      0.000000000 1        Low
49812105    R       0.003298709 1        Low
49812105    P       0.000000855 1        Low
49812105    B       0.131147541 1        Low
49812105    Bi      0.000350086 1        Low
```

So, I would like a bar plot of how much of each bacteria is in each category. So it should be 4 plots, for each bacteria, with value on the y-axis and food category on the x-axis.

I have tried this code:

```
library(dplyr)
genus_veg %>% group_by(Genus, Abundance) %>% summarise(Abundance = sum(Abundance)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Level, y= Abundance, fill = Genus)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But get this error:

```
Error: cannot modify grouping variable
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please can you edit so the data.frame column names and the variables names in the code match. Have you looked at `facet_wrap`?

Comment: @RichardTelford I have changed the data and split them into 4 groups. The new code is now edited. Do you please have any suggestions?

Comment: @surreals which variable in your data frame is the food category?

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR** Plotting by [facets](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)*

How you posed the question is *super unclear*. So I have interpreted your question from

> So, I would like a bar plot of how much of each bacteria is in each category. So it should be 4 plots, for each bacteria, with value on the y-axis and food category on the x-axis.

as:

- You want a bar chart
- You want 4 plots, one for each of the bacteria types: R, B, P, Bi
- x-axis = food category
- y-axis = abundance of bacteria

### Input

In regards to the input data, the data was unclear e.g. you did not describe what "Sample", "Level", or "Category" is. Ideally, you would keep all the food category in one data frame. e.g.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## The categories you have defined
bacteria <- c("R", "B", "P", "Bi")
food <- c("FiberCategory", "FruitCategory", "VegetablesCategory", "WholegrainCategory")

## Create dummy data for plotting
set.seed(1)
num_rows <- length(bacteria)
num_cols <- length(food)
dummydata <- 
  matrix(data = abs(rnorm(num_rows*num_cols, mean=0.01, sd=0.05)),
         nrow=num_rows, ncol=num_cols)
rownames(dummydata) <- bacteria
colnames(dummydata) <- food
dummydata <-
  dummydata %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("bacteria") %>% 
  gather(food, abundance, -bacteria)
```

of which the output looks like:

```
#> dummydata
#   bacteria               food   abundance
#1         R      FiberCategory 0.021322691
#2         B      FiberCategory 0.019182166
#3         P      FiberCategory 0.031781431
#4        Bi      FiberCategory 0.089764040
#5         R      FruitCategory 0.026475389
#6         B      FruitCategory 0.031023419
#7         P      FruitCategory 0.034371453
#8        Bi      FruitCategory 0.046916235
#9         R VegetablesCategory 0.038789068
#10        B VegetablesCategory 0.005269419
#11        P VegetablesCategory 0.085589058
#12       Bi VegetablesCategory 0.029492162
#13        R WholegrainCategory 0.021062029
#14        B WholegrainCategory 0.100734994
#15        P WholegrainCategory 0.066246546
#16       Bi WholegrainCategory 0.007753320
```

### Plot

Once you have the data formatted as above, you can simply do:

```
dummydata %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = food,
             y = abundance,
             group = bacteria)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +

  ## Split into 4 plots 
  ## Note: can also use 'facet_grid' to do this
  facet_wrap(~bacteria) +
  theme(
    ## rotate the x-axis label
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=.5)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR** Combine individual plots with [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)*

In another interpretation of the *super unclear* question, this time from:

> Plotting Bacteria according to Food Groups & Abundance in R

and

> would like to plot them according to their food categories: "FiberCategory", "FruitCategory", "VegetablesCategory" & "WholegrainCategory." I have made 4 separate files

You might be asking for:

- You want a bar chart
- You want 4 plots, one for each of the food categories
- x-axis = bacteria type
- y-axis = abundance of bacteria

### Input

Let say you have a data frame for each food category. (Again, I'm using dummy data)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## The categories you have defined
bacteria <- c("R", "B", "P", "Bi")
food <- c("FiberCategory", "FruitCategory", "VegetablesCategory", "WholegrainCategory")

## Create dummy data for plotting
set.seed(1)
num_rows <- length(bacteria)
num_cols <- length(food)
dummydata <- 
  matrix(data = abs(rnorm(num_rows*num_cols, mean=0.01, sd=0.05)),
         nrow=num_rows, ncol=num_cols)
rownames(dummydata) <- bacteria
colnames(dummydata) <- food
dummydata <-
  dummydata %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("bacteria") %>% 
  gather(food, abundance, -bacteria)


## If we have 4 data frames
filter_food <- function(dummydata, foodcat){
  dummydata %>%
    filter(food == foodcat) %>% 
    select(-food)
}
dd_fiber <- filter_food(dummydata, "FiberCategory")
dd_fruit <- filter_food(dummydata, "FruitCategory")
dd_veg <- filter_food(dummydata, "VegetablesCategory")
dd_grain <- filter_food(dummydata, "WholegrainCategory")
```

Where one data frame looks something like

```
#> dd_grain
#  bacteria  abundance
#1        R 0.02106203
#2        B 0.10073499
#3        P 0.06624655
#4       Bi 0.00775332
```

### Plot

You can create separate plots. (Here, I'm using a function to generate my plots)

```
plot_food <- function(dd, title=""){
  dd %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = bacteria, y = abundance)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    ggtitle(title)
}
plt_fiber <- plot_food(dd_fiber, "fiber")
plt_fruit <- plot_food(dd_fruit, "fruit")
plt_veg <- plot_food(dd_veg, "veg")
plt_grain <- plot_food(dd_grain, "grain")
```

And then combine them using [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plt_fiber, plt_fruit, plt_veg, plt_grain)
```

[image]